# How to style the remaining space in Canvas

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a canvas with an image filling it end to end. I would like to style it and highlight focus on the face area.

Below is what I would like to achieve.

[image]

Here is what I have so far:

[image]

Note the face area should be transparent and the rest blurred.

Here is my code:

```
var ctx = context.drawImage(, 0, 0, 500, 500);
drawROI(ctx, width / 4, 50, 250, 350);

drawROI(ctx, x, y, w, h) {
  var kappa = 0.5522848,
    ox = (w / 2) * kappa,
    oy = (h / 2) * kappa,
    xe = x + w,
    ye = y + h,
    xm = x + w / 2,
    ym = y + h / 2;

  // Draw Oval
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x, ym);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(x, ym - oy, xm - ox, y, xm, y);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(xm + ox, y, xe, ym - oy, xe, ym);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(xe, ym + oy, xm + ox, ye, xm, ye);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(xm - ox, ye, x, ym + oy, x, ym);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#999";

  // Draw Rectange
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(0, 0, this.video.width, this.video.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

Note: The `drawROI` is where everything happens. The canvas already has an image, then I draw the oval and then the rectangle.My idea was to push the rectangle at the back and have the face being displayed in the oval clearly.

How can I achieve a similar UI as show in image 1 above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is real-time. You will need to create a 2 canvases to help with the FX.

The frosted glass is on one layer. To avoid setting the blur filter overhead the filter is left on at all times.

The second layer is the inset window. An ellipse is draw and then the image over that using composite operation `"source-in"` (only pixels set get changed)

The final step draws the two layers onto the canvas and then adds the border and highlights as ellipses.

The demo has a random image and animates its position (just to check performance as blur can be costly)

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillText("Loading image please wait..", 10,20)
Math.TAU = Math.PI * 2;
const img = new Image;
img.src = "http://www.createjs.com/demos/_assets/art/flowers.jpg";


img.onload = () => {

    // settings
    const blurAmount = 12; // in pixels
    const glassBlur = "blur(" + blurAmount + "px)"; // the blur filter
    const glassColor = "#EEE";
    const glassOpacity = 0.45;
    const faceRadius2 = canvas.height * (1/4);
    const faceRadius1 = canvas.width * (1/3);
    const borderWidth = canvas.width * (1/25);
    const insetBorderColor = "#999";
    const highlightColor = "255,255,255";

    // background image holds frosty glass
    const bg = document.createElement("canvas");
    bg.width = canvas.width;
    bg.height = canvas.height;
    bg.ctx = bg.getContext("2d");
    bg.ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    bg.ctx.filter = glassBlur;   // IMPORTANT TO SET FILTER EARLY or will cause
                                         // slowdown is done on the fly

    // create the mask for the window
    const windowMask = document.createElement("canvas");
    windowMask.width = canvas.width;
    windowMask.height = canvas.height;
    windowMask.ctx = windowMask.getContext("2d");

    // create the gradient for the highlights
    const highlight = ctx.createLinearGradient(
        0,
        canvas.height / 2 - faceRadius1 + borderWidth,
        0,
        canvas.height / 2 + faceRadius1 - borderWidth,
    );
    highlight.addColorStop(0,  "rgba("+highlightColor +",1)");
    highlight.addColorStop(0.25,"rgba("+highlightColor +",0.4)");
    highlight.addColorStop(0.5,"rgba("+highlightColor +",0)");
    highlight.addColorStop(0.75,"rgba("+highlightColor +",0.4)");
    highlight.addColorStop(1,  "rgba("+highlightColor +",1)");

    ctx.lineCap = "round"; // for the highlight

    var x,y; //position of image for demo

    // animate moving image
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    function loop(time) {
        x = -(Math.cos(time / 2000) * 20 + 20);
        y = -(Math.sin(time / 2000) * 20 + 20);
        frosty(img);
        faceWindow(img);
        drawFace();
        requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    
    }

    // draws frosted glass to bg canvas
    function frosty(img) {
         const w = bg.width;
         const h = bg.height;
         bg.ctx.drawImage(img, x, y);
         bg.ctx.fillStyle = glassColor;
         bg.ctx.globalAlpha = glassOpacity;
         bg.ctx.fillRect(-blurAmount, -blurAmount, w + blurAmount * 2, h + blurAmount * 2); 
         bg.ctx.globalAlpha = 1;

    }
   

    // creates inset window
    function faceWindow(img) {
        const w = windowMask.width;
        const h = windowMask.height;
        windowMask.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
        windowMask.ctx.beginPath();
        windowMask.ctx.ellipse(w / 2, h / 2, faceRadius1, faceRadius2, 0, 0, Math.TAU);
        windowMask.ctx.fill();
        windowMask.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
        windowMask.ctx.drawImage(img, x, y,); // draw face 
        windowMask.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    }


    // puts it all together.
    function drawFace() {
        const w = canvas.width;
        const h = canvas.height;
        ctx.drawImage(bg, 0, 0); // draw glass
        ctx.drawImage(windowMask, 0, 0); // draw face in window

        // draw border
        ctx.lineWidth = borderWidth;
        ctx.strokeStyle = insetBorderColor;

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.ellipse(w / 2, h / 2, faceRadius1, faceRadius2, 0, 0, Math.TAU);
        ctx.stroke();

        // draw highlights
        ctx.strokeStyle = highlight;  // gradient
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";
        ctx.globalAlpha = 0.65;

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.ellipse(w / 2, h / 2, faceRadius1 - borderWidth * 2, faceRadius2 - borderWidth * 2, 0, 0, Math.PI / 2);
        ctx.stroke();
        
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.ellipse(w / 2, h / 2, faceRadius1 - borderWidth * 2, faceRadius2 - borderWidth * 2, 0, Math.PI, Math.PI * 1.5);
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
        ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    }
}
```

```css
canvas { border: 2px solid black; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="350"> </canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I'll finalize the implementation and update you on the speed or resource used. The source is Webcam, I've FX already handled.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by applying all needed effects on the entire image, and then drawing required part of the clear image on top of all the effects.

Given an original image:

[image: original]

Canvas [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/filter) property can be used to produce all kinds of effects. For example here, we enable blur and sepia filters and after that when drawing an image, it will have these effects applied.

```
context.filter = 'blur(4px) sepia(1)';
context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 400, 400);
context.filter = 'none';
```

[image: filters]

Then, we need to clear a shape (in your case it is an [ellipse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/ellipse)) from this image, so it can later be filled with a unfiltered clear image. It can be done by using [globalCompositeOperation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) canvas property - it allows to compose different sources into a final drawing.

`destination-out` value has the following behavior - the existing content is kept where it doesn't overlap the new shape, i.e. when we draw a shape with this mode on, the filtered image will remain the same, but the shape will be cleared.

```
context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
context.ellipse(200, 80, 80, 100, 0, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
context.fill();
```

[image: clear shape]

Finally we can use another composite operation to fill this empty shape with a clear image.

`destination-atop` will draw new clear image "behind" filtered image, but because we have a "hole" in filtered image, it will show up exactly where we need it.

```
context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-atop';
context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 400, 400);
```

[image: final]

See JSBin for full source: https://jsbin.com/socexefawu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks for the support. I'd like to implement this and @Blindman67 answer above and measure performance. This is pretty cool and easy. Thanks